# tkinter LabelFrame center text

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to center text in the frame using LabelFrame function. My code is below.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(
            master=window,
            relief=tk.RAISED,
            borderwidth=5,
            width=50,
            height=50,
            text=i+j,
            labelanchor = 'n'
        )
        frame.grid(row=i, column=j)
window.geometry("500x500")
window.mainloop()
```

Argument *labelanchor* that specify position gives only options on the edge of the frame. Is there any simple way to center text inside of the frame using *LabelFrame*?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Label` with border instead of `LabelFrame`?

Comment: This is my first program with tkinter and function I found was LabelFrame. I saw people using Label to center but I was wondering if it is also possible with LabelFrame.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any simple way to center text inside of the frame using LabelFrame?

The text of the labelframe can only appear along the edges of the frame. If you wish for text to appear inside the frame, you must create a `Label` and add it to the frame.

### Using a frame and a label

If you wish to put other widgets in the frame and don't want this text to interfere with the other widgets, this is a perfect opportunity to use `place`.

The following example adds the label "Hello, world" to appear in the center of the widget. A button is placed in the frame just to show that its placement is not affected by the label, or vise versa. The screenshots show what the frame looks like naturally and when the window is resized.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lf = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief="groove")
lf_label = tk.Label(lf, text="Hello, world")
lf_label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
lf.pack(padx=20, pady=20, fill="both", expand=True)

b = tk.Button(lf, text="Click me")
b.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of original window]
[image: screenshot of resized window]

### Using only a label

You can add widgets inside any other widget. So, instead of a frame you could just use a label. By default, the text will be centered, and just like with the previous example it won't affect the layout of other widgets.

I haven't included screenshots because the results are identical to the previous example.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lf = tk.Label(text="Hello, world", bd=2, relief="groove")
lf.pack(padx=20, pady=20, fill="both", expand=True)

b = tk.Button(lf, text="Click me")
b.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```